# Function that calculates total gravitational force vector

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested-loops

So I am really stuck on this, but I need to define a function that uses nested loops to calculate the total gravitational vector from all other particles in an n body system. I already have a function defined with inputs (mass1, mass2, position1, position2) that calculates the force vector and outputs it as an array for only two bodies though. I would like to utilize this function in the function I am trying to define. The function I want to define takes inputs as (m,p) where m is a list of the particle's masses and p is an array of arrays of each position vector of each particle. If someone could just explain how to do this please. I don't need or want exact code, but just an explanation for how to go about it with nested loops. Thank you!!

Comment: Why exactly do you _need_ nested loops? Shouldn't it be sufficient to take your one particle and loop through the list of all other particles, applying their gravitational vectors one by one, in a single layer?

Comment: Because I am defining a function and I won't know how many particles there are,  I want it to be a function I can use not just once but many times